# Problems with removing admin bar

Tags: plugin-development, functions, wp-admin, admin-bar, pluggable

I am trying to remove the admin bar from a theme front end of a theme.

I found the following code block:

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
remove_action( 'personal_options', '_admin_bar_preferences' );
```

Which works fine. *However* I wanted to add a choice for the user, so that I can add a permanent code block to my boilerplate theme, and allow users to toggle the admin bar off and on.

I have successfully added the toggle in the admin area, and called back the value successfully, however, when I test for the value in order to control the callback of the admin bar, the admin bar goes, but the CSS applied to the HTML element (`margin-top: 28px !important;`) remains, leaving a 28px gap in the top of my theme.

Here is the code block I am using to call the value back, and respond accordingly:

```
function block_admin(){
    $show = get_option('admin_bar_');
    $show = $show['admin_bar_toggle'];
    if (!$show || $show != 'on'){
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
        remove_action( 'personal_options', '_admin_bar_preferences' );
    } 
}
add_action('init', 'block_admin');
```

---

**Suggestion**

By requirement, my custom option (using `register_setting`) is not initialised until the `admin_menu` hook is launched, whilst the `block_admin` is launched on `init`. However, I don't think this is the issue as I don't think `get_option` is dependent on the setting being registered, but rather the option existing (or not) in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just launching the function at an earlier point solved the issue

```
 function block_admin(){
    $show = get_option('admin_bar_');
    $show = $show['admin_bar_toggle'];
    fb::log($show,'shoe');
    if (!$show || $show != 'on'){
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
        remove_action( 'personal_options', '_admin_bar_preferences' );
    } 
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','block_admin');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already an per-user-option to disable the admin-bar in the latest Wordpress versions. It can be found in the user profile settings:

…/wp-admin/profile.php (click on your name after logging in)

Comment: I am removing that as well. In short, I don't like the admin bar.

Comment: "I don't like the admin bar" Who does? Mostly it also heavily interacts with the theme, resulting in spaces somewhere…

Comment: Having it on as default was a big mistake, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried [`show_admin_bar(false)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar)? From quick look at code is should kill admin bar and it is safe to run very early (on load actually).

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved your settings, so that they *do* exist in the database?

Also: what if you change this:

```
if ( ! $show || $show != 'on' ) {
```

...to this:

```
if ( ! isset( $show ) || $show != 'on' ) {
```

Comment: I am sure the if statement is not the problem, as it does do something, and that something is reversible when I toggle the control back and forth. It removes the bar itself, just not the style applied to the `html` element.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that matches you req.
But here is plugin to toogle admin bar on off globaly. Why not have a look :)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/global-admin-bar-hide-or-remove/