# What is the very earliest action hook you can call?

Tags: filters, actions, wp-load.php, init

After the solution to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23453/problems-with-removing-admin-bar/23629#23629) was to get a function to launch BEFORE the `init` action is fired by taking the sequence out of its function, it got me thinking, is there any earlier in the WP load sequence that I can hook a function into?

Comment: I really wish they would have added a plugin call *before* the whole system was loaded.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`muplugins_loaded`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded) is the earliest hook.

> Depending on your wordpress setup, you may not have any plugins in the `MU_PLUGINS` directory. In that case this hook may not fire.

The next best hook to trigger is [`plugins_loaded`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded).

**RESOURCES**

1. [WordPress Codex - Action Reference List](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)
2. Q/A: [How to get WordPress' hook run sequence?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162869/84219)
3. Q/A: [Make sense of WP Load Core](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/22534)

Comment: Yep, but note that it runs before loading of normal plugins and theme so it is somewhat useless in practice. `plugins_loaded` and `after_setup_theme` are earliest appropriate for normal plugins and theme accordingly.

Comment: answer updated.  check desired action with **"Hooks run list"**.

Comment: This answer contains some very bad information. The `muplugins_loaded` action [is not conditional on anything](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-settings.php#L229) . It will fire. If there are no mu-plugins, though, I am not sure how you'd get code to run before early enough to use the hook.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone interested in finding this out on your own, there is an awesome plugin named [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).

Install and activate the plugin (on staging or dev install obviously) and just select what you want from the drop down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment on the accepted answer, the hook [muplugins_loaded](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded) is not conditional. If you read the source code you will find that it is always fired - at least in recent versions of WordPress. According to the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) it is also the first available hook. However, unless you are actually writing a must-use or network activated plugin it doesn't make much sense to use it since *it will fire before your plugin or theme is loaded*.

If you are writing a plugin, then the [plugins_loaded](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded) is the first general action hook to use.

If you are adding code to your theme's functions.php, then you could use [after_setup_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme).