# include plugin folder directly in theme folder to load faster page n wp

Tags: plugins, uploads

include plugin folder directly in theme folder to load faster page in wp?
Load jquery in the footer and the jquery load from plugin installed also.

Comment: Please try to ask a real question. I have no idea what problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

First check out the super-post by @Rarst [Between functions.php, widgets and plugins, which is loaded first?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first)

If you load jQuery always enqueue it to avoid conflicts: [Include jQuery in WordPress Theme](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/) and also check out this article: [The Developer’s Guide To Conflict-Free JavaScript And CSS In WordPress](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/12/developers-guide-conflict-free-javascript-css-wordpress/)