# Admin: global $post empty

Tags: admin, actions, variables

I tried to get $post var outside function php in wordpress admin panel.
The only way that I find to access to $post is to add_action.

However I want to get this var outside the add_action and global var seems to doesn't work in add_action.

How can I get $post in admin panel outside function.php.

I search during hours an can't find a solution...

EDIT: Example

```
require_once(TP_PLUGIN_PATH . 'includes/my-file-framework.php' ); // it'a a metabox framework
require_once(TP_PLUGIN_PATH . 'includes/my-file-config.php' ); // I load the     file that include metabox array to build metabox

class The_plugin_Admin {

    public function __construct() {
       add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array($this, 'the_metabox' ));
    }

    public function the_metabox() {
        apply_filters( 'the_metabox_setup','');
    }

}

new The_plugin_Admin;
```

And my-file-config.php where I wan to retrieve Wordpress global:

```
 add_filter( 'the_metabox_setup', 'the_metabox_setup_callback' );
 function the_metabox_setup_callback() {
      global $post;
      print_r($post); //empty
      $post_ID = isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : 0;
      echo $post_ID; // empty on new post because not already set

      $post_types = get_post_types(array('public' => true), 'names', 'and'); // no get all post type on the first time, need to loop again to get all

      $an_array[] = array(......);
      $an_array[] = array(......);
      $an_array[] = array(......);
      $an_array[] = array(......);

      foreach ($an_array as $array) {
           new The_Metabox($array); // contruct my metabox, the class was declared previous in my-file-framework.php
      }

 }
```

Comment: Reduce the globals. Use the function `get_current_screen()`. You find inside the array of the result of this function the page, the post type and more. Small hint, easy to find with plugin "Debug Objects".

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work, it's undefined...

Comment: If is undefined, then was include via wrong hook.

Comment: So which hook do I need to used to get for example post ID in post type edit page in admin?

Comment: That is not easy to answer. Have you check with the Plugin Debug Objects? Also see this source AS example, very often I check the screen values - https://github.com/bueltge/Archive/blob/master/archive.php

Comment: With the hook 'pre_get_posts' it works finally; This is the only one to work for my needs after trying a lot of hooks!

Comment: But it seems to not work when on new post edit page. It only works if I edit thean existing post...

Comment: Can you post your source, maybe this helps to understand the structure, your problem.

Comment: I just updated the code. See my EDIT question.

Comment: Maybe I can send you the plugin if you want? Do you have a mail? I really need to understand what I doing wrong. I want to learn more about it. I think my mistake is something simple but I miss something stupid I guess.

Comment: Your last edition is quite ..... You ask about `global $curent_screen` issue but you are not using it in your code. How do you expect we can help you? Please, edit your question again to add the appropiate code and example that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Now you have changed the question from `global $current_screen` to `global $post` but still you don't show us how are you using it. Your code doesn't use `global $post` anywhere. If you don't describe your problem properly is quite sure that you won't get a good answer.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Your actual problem is easy: `pre_get_posts` is a filter running _before_ the posts are fetched. Therefore the `global $post` can be filled yet (that can be even extracted from the name of the filter).

Answer (score 5):

The basic mistake is, that every data is available at the point where you write your code. That isn't the case and hooks are there to provide access to the core code during different states of the [core loading procedure <sup>graph</sup>](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71411/385).

In short and *very* simplified things run `like` this:

```
# core loads
// ...more stuff...
# point at where all must-use-plugins are loaded - first entry point
do_action( 'muplugins_loaded' );
// ...more stuff...
# point at where all plugins are loaded - second entry point
do_action( 'plugins_loaded' );
// ...more stuff...
# main core stuff available - use this hook instead of `init` for multisite plugins
do_action( 'wp_loaded' );
// ...more stuff...
# themes functions.php files loaded - use this hook for theme stuff
do_action( 'after_setup_theme' );
// ...rendering happens...
```

Somewhere in between, WP core sets up (fills with data) different `global`ly available datasets in global variables. Some are defined during the rendering flow, others before it, etc. In other words, when you write a plugin and just drop code in the wild (not in a callback attached to a hook or filter), then it's very uncertain where it will appear. In your example possibly before `plugins_loaded` is called. The result is either a PHP error (undefined variable) or just something empty, because the variable wasn't filled.

Conclusion: **Always!** put your code in callbacks that are attached to (the appropriate) hooks and filters. In most cases this means a bit of *shotgun* debugging and attaching your callbacks to different hooks/filters that you find when following the core loading procedure with reading core files.

Short cut to data available in the admin and on which hook it is available via the [wecodemore/"Current Admin Info"-Plugin](http://bit.ly/admin-info).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I need to learn more about it... I will try to make it works, and will take inspiration of your plugin.

Comment: I tried during hours but I still don't understand... I think I miss something... For example I include a file and I just want to retrieve post id for example. But I can't access to it inside the included file...

Comment: @freaky Please update your question with your current code so I can see what's going wrong.