# How to list all the posts in a personalized page? WordPress

Tags: php, posts

Well, I created a custom page where I need it to return **all** the posts that have registered on the site, like the index. I tried to do in the normal way, by creating a custom page and assigning it the same code found in index.php, however when I try to list all the posts he just returns me to the page like a publishing page.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Novos Posts
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div class="cont_marg">
    <div class="pad_sd">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <ul class="lista-filmes">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE); ?>
                    <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <div class="titulo-box open-sans">
                            <h2 class="titulo-box-link">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="capa">
                            <div class="fluccs">
                                <div class="boxxer"><?php echo $my_meta['durat']; ?>min</div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="absolute-capa no-text effect"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(158,226)); ?>
                            <div class="flutuador" style="background:none;">
                                <div class="audioy"><?php echo the_qualt($my_meta['qualt']); ?></div>
                                <div class="anolanc"><?php echo $my_meta['ano']; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="views"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?> visitas</div>
                    </li><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php post_pagination();?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .pad_sd -->
</div><!-- .cont_marg -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You know when we create a personalized page? Ready just that I do not want this page to be a post, I want it to return me all the posts I already have, but she did not return what she weighs it be the same ... Understand?

Comment: Why cant you use the archive?  Are you familiar with the hierarchy of WordPress: [Is there a flowchart for wordpress loading sequence?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence).  When you say "registered" do you mean published?

Comment: Can you try, going to `Settings > Reading` and select your personalized page in the `Posts page` drop down and see if it works.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty simple way to query outside the loop using [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Setting `post_status => 'any'` could net you all.

The code below queries posts, pages and attachments. The loops through and outputs them all to an unordered list.

```
$pages = get_posts( array(
  'post_type'   => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'any', 
  'numberposts' => -1, 
));

$posts = get_posts( array(
  'post_type'   => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'any', 
  'numberposts' => -1,
));

$attachments = get_posts( array(
  'post_type'   => 'attachment',
  'post_status' => 'any', 
  'numberposts' => -1,
));


echo '<ul>';

echo '<li><h2>POSTS</h2></li>';

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $link = get_the_permalink ( $post->ID );
    echo "<li>{$post->post_type} - {$post->post_status} - {$post->ID} - <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$link}\">{$post->post_title}</a></li>";    
}

echo '<li><h2>PAGES</h2></li>';

foreach ( $pages as $post ) {
    $link = get_the_permalink ( $post->ID );
    echo "<li>{$post->post_type} - {$post->post_status} - {$post->ID} - <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$link}\">{$post->post_title}</a></li>";    
}

echo '<li><h2>ATTACHMENTS</h2></li>';

foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
    $link = get_the_permalink ( $post->ID );
    echo "<li>{$post->post_type} - {$post->post_status} - {$post->ID} - <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$link}\">{$post->post_title}</a></li>";    
}

echo '</ul>';
```

If you really want to grab it all:

```
$any = get_posts( array(
  'post_type'   => 'any',
  'post_status' => 'any', 
  'numberposts' => -1, 
));
```