# In a plugin, why is add_action('init') not executed before the plugin is activated?

Tags: plugin-development, actions

I'm new to Wordpress development (and php in general) so I'm confused about the execution of functions in my plugin's php file.  I've seen multiple guides that show to create a `register_activation_hook` function, that is executed when the plugin is activated.  However, after the activation hook function, there is always an `add_action('init')` call that adds a bunch of options to the database.

So my question is: when Wordpress evaluates my plugin's php file, and finds the `register_activation_hook` call, why does it not execute the `add_action('init')` call until *after* the plugin is activated?  If Wordpress evaluates my plugin's php file, and there is a function call to `add_action('init')` in the file, it seems like that function call would execute when the page is evaluated, because it's not inside a control structure.

I know Wordpress is evaluating this file before it's activated, because it knows my plugin name, and author, and all that before it's activated.  So if it's evaluating the file, why is it not executing the `add_action('init')` call?

Does my question make sense?  Can anyone help me to understand why things are working this way?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'halloween_store_install');

function halloween_store_install() {
    $hween_options_arr = array(
        'currency_sign' => '$'
    );

    //save our default option values
    update_option( 'halloween_options', $hween_options_arr );
}

add_action( 'init', 'halloween_store_init' ); // <-- why is this not executed until my plugin is activated?

function halloween_store_init(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Products', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Product', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Products', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Product', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Products', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No products found', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in Trash', 'halloween-plugin' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Products', 'halloween-plugin' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_ui_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'halloween-products', $args);
}
```

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71411/170), a separate answer is in my opinion not necessary, is redundant. As small hint, if you will work with the plugin "Debug Objects" you can see the stacktrace, the hooks in the order, there is fired.

Comment: @bueltge while that flow chart is helpful, it only illustrated when entire files are executed.  Since this `add_action('init')` call is in the same file as my plugin name and the `register_activation_hook` call, why is it not getting called when the rest of the file is being evaluated?

Comment: You have two functions and you fired this different, on two different hooks. The order is in advice of the core, how runs the hooks in the core. Also you should fire your plugin on a hook, like  `plugins_loaded` and not automatically via the include the file.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to know why the `add_action` function is not run while being  in the same file as `register_activation_hook`.  Because nothing is run at the include level in WP, everything depends on the hook sequence.  So basically it is evaluated when PHP reads that file, but it will be executed when the hook is called.  This makes it possible to build plugins and call functions conditionally and also respect a certain sequence logic in the application.

Comment: If we didn't have that, we'd get a bunch of errors because some functions would be called before the the application would be loaded and depending variables and constant not defined yet.  Basically, `add_action`, `add_filter` and `register_activation_hook` (and others) are PHP's `call_user_func` but with some added context so it's easier to understand what is being called and when.  Hope this makes more sense to you

Comment: @bynicolas Okay this is making sense.  However if the `add_action('init')` in my plugin's php file is evaluated, then why isn't it executed when the `init` hook is called, until after my plugin is activated?  From what I understand `init` is a global hook that is fired when Wordpress is loading.  However, the function I'm hooking into `init` is not executed unless my plugin is activated.  How is this possible?

Comment: This is exactly one example of the conditional scenario I'm talking about, the `init` action for your plugin depends on the activation of your plugin to run, if WP doesn't see your plugin as being activated, it won't run the rest of the code in your plugin files

Comment: @bynicolas okay, so then before my plugin is activated, Wordpress only reads the file enough to get the name, but doesn't actually evaluate any of the rest of the php file?  Then, once the plugin is activated, Wordpress evaluates the rest of the file?

Comment: Correct, if you look at any plugin, you will find comments in the main file which contains the plugin name, version, author, etc.  This is what is read and shows in your plugin list. Then, if your plugin is activated, the rest will follow the hook sequence

Comment: @bynicolas okay, so I guess Wordpress simply uses text processing to extract the name, version, author, etc before it's activated.  Then adds the file to the php pipeline after it's activated.  Can you add this info as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44652/discussion-between-tyler-jones-and-bynicolas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is an application and everything that is run within that application is called by hooks.

Then 2 main hook functions are [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and [`add_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/), but as you saw, [`register_activation_hook`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) and [`register_deactivation_hook`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) are other functions that are used in the context of activation and deactivation.

There exist more hook defining functions, like functions that will hook time sensitive actions (pseudo cron) like [`wp_schedule_event`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) for instance.

The codex offers a good list of available action hooks (ordered by their generaly called sequence) to be used with [`add_actions`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and filters to be used with [`add_filter`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

I am not aware of such a list for all hooks defining functions.

Like I said in my comment, most of these functions are simply intelligent wrappers for PHP's [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) functions that give context to these hooks.

So when a plugin or theme is installed, it won't automatically run even though their files would technically be read (at least the main files are).

In the main file of a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) or [theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), you will find a comment section defining the parameter of the plugin/theme, such as theme name, author, version, etc.

In themes, the `style.css` file would be read and would contain something similar to this

```
/*
 Theme Name: Twenty Thirteen
 Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen
 Author: the WordPress team
 Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
 Description: The 2013 theme for WordPress takes us back to the blog, featuring a full range of post formats, each displayed beautifully in their own unique way. Design details abound, starting with a vibrant color scheme and matching header images, beautiful typography and icons, and a flexible layout that looks great on any device, big or small.
 Version: 1.0
 License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags: black, brown, orange, tan, white, yellow, light, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-width, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, translation-ready
 Text Domain: twentythirteen

 This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
 Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

Similarly, in a plugin's main PHP file, you would find a comment section containing something similar to this

```
/*
 Plugin Name: My Toolset
 Plugin URI:  http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
 Description: This describes my plugin in a short sentence
 Version:     1.5
 Author:      John Smith
 Author URI:  http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
 License:     GPL2
 License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Domain Path: /languages
 Text Domain: my-toolset
*/
```

Finally, once a theme/plugin is activated, then it will go on loading the rest of it's files following WP's hook loading sequence and load everything that the developers hooked to these action hooks or filters.

And in those developer's created functions, all the magic happens for that particular plugin or theme.

A pretty comprehensive and worth reading explanation of WP load sequence was made by userabuser [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71411/99217).