# What hook is the currently active theme's functions.php file loaded on?

Tags: themes, hooks, actions, wp-load.php

At which point of hook execution is the currently activated theme's `functions.php` file loaded?

Comment: it's arround `setup_themes`, look this : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is included from `/wp-settings.php` right after the action `setup_theme`. Line number 423 as of WordPress 4.7