# WordPress undefined function error on using add_action() in functions.php

Tags: functions, hooks

In `functions.php`, I have added the following code

```
function my_custom_js() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=58ef5701485778001223c86c&product=inline-share-buttons"></script>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_js');
```

This gives an error:

> undefined function add_action()

But this is already defined by WordPress. Am I missing something?

Comment: where is your functions.php file located?

Comment: @rajith is your function is inside a class?

Answer (score 1):

If [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) is undefined, it means WP is not loaded in the regular way. Assuming we are talking about `functions.php` in the theme folder (and not the `functions.php` in the `wp-includes` folder, which you must not mess with) there should be no problem, unless the php-file itself is run outside WP.

This could happen, for instance, if you are including the php-file with a full url, in which case WP would see it as an external source, to be evaluated outside the WP-context. In that case `add_action` would be undefined. Normally, this would not happen, because WP itself looks for the `functions.php` file in the active (child) theme, but messing up the normal way of things is certainly possible.

There is not enough context in your question to pinpoint where this could happen, but I suggest you check all `include` and `require`statements in your theme. Also, [this may be a useful resource](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence) to track where things go wrong.

Answer (score -1):

@rajith try this. This might be helps you-

```
add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'my_custom_js'));
```

Comment: it working on class-based coding... his coding is not class based. :)