# Cached php? Updates are rendering only if logged as admin

Tags: wp-admin, cache

I was asked to fix a wordpress based site and I don't get what's going on with it.

The (custom) theme has a `page-home.php` that is the Home page.

Whatever edits I make to this file, if I refresh the page logged in wp-admin (so, I'm an admin), the change is seen, but logged out (anonymous - as the site is intended to be used) it's still the old content.

I did the following:

- downloaded all site locally, opened all `*.php` files, and searched for duplicate similar homepage sites, just in case a different one is served for anonymous browsing - no duplicate files
- searched for keywords like `is_admin`, `is_user_logged_in`, didn't find such logic
- went through [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence) to get what the order of execution is in WP. Helped a bit but didn't help me solve the problem
- hardcoded things in `header.php` file -> result only displayed while logged in.

I don't know how else to find out why I keep getting old page.

I assume wordpress is rendering some pages, but why doesn't use the latest changes if anonymous? How to fix this?

Comment: Really sounds like you're using a caching plugin of some kind. Are you sure you're not? WP Super Cache? W3 Total Cache? WP Rocket? Litespeed Cache?

Comment: Either I'm not using or it doesn't contain cache or rocket in title: *No plugins found for “cache”*. I just gave a quick scan over all active plugins (eyeballing them) and none of them seem related to caching...

Comment: @JacobPeattie I just see now that W3 Total Cache was installed. I see a w3tc-config folder. But the plugin doesn't appear in the plugins folder

Comment: If you can't see a caching solution, the next step is to check your wp-content dir for a cache-folder & your .htaccess for any caching rules which may exist without a plugin. The text may also be modified by a js-script (food for thought)

Comment: @Adelin just read your last comment, you should be okay if you remove the cache-filder and any rewrite rules that go with them. The rewrite rules would be in .htaccess on apache & nginx.conf on nginx.

Comment: I deleted the w3tc folder, checked htaccess and see no rules related to caching and yet the same behavior occurs. ugh...

Comment: Can it really be a caching problem if it is related to whether or not you are logged in?

Comment: Yes. Caching is typically configured to be turned off for logged-in users.

Comment: In fact, it's a strong 'tell' that the issue is caused by a caching plugin. In your case it looks like a caching plugin wasn't uninstalled properly. You should contact W3TC support for help properly uninstalling. 3rd-party plugin support is off-topic.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for these insights. I have one last potentially important info: the mobile version of the site, even as anonymous, loads latest changes. So only the desktop version of anonymous users are loading old data

Comment: Are you using a mobile theme of some kind? Like WP Touch or Jetpack's mobile theme? They're often cached separately, or not at all. And have you tried a different browser or private browsing to be sure it's not just browser caching.

Comment: @JacobPeattie no, didnt use such theme. It is a custom theme. Anyway, I sort of fixed my own issue with the hack from the answer I provided. I don't love it but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I deleted cache folders, I removed plenty plugins, edited `.htaccess` files, etc and still didn't work.

I figured, if cache issues are lost after login, and since this site is designed to be used anonymously - well then log a fake user in.

1. I created a user `anonuser` with subscriber role
2. I added in `functions.php` this code to auto login ([source](https://gist.github.com/cliffordp/e8d1d9f732328ba360ad)):

   ```
   function auto_login() {
     $loginusername = 'anonuser';
     if (!is_user_logged_in()) { 
       //get user's ID
       $user = get_user_by('login', $loginusername);
       $user_id = $user->ID;
       wp_set_current_user($user_id, $loginusername);
       wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
       do_action('wp_login', $loginusername);
       show_admin_bar(false);
       exit;
     }
   }
   add_action('wp', 'auto_login');
   ```
3. Lastly, just in case someone visits `wp-admin` manually, log them out and show the login page ([source](https://alka-web.com/blog/how-to-restrict-access-to-wordpress-dashboard-programmatically/)):

   ```
   add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_dashboard_access_handler');

   function my_custom_dashboard_access_handler() {

     // Check if the current page is an admin page
     // && and ensure that this is not an ajax call
     if ( is_admin() && !( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ){

       //Get all capabilities of the current user
       $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
       $caps = ( is_object( $user) ) ? array_keys($user->allcaps) : array();

       //All capabilities/roles listed here are not able to see the dashboard
       $block_access_to = array('subscriber', 'contributor', 'my-custom-role', 'my-custom-capability');

       if(array_intersect($block_access_to, $caps)) {
         wp_logout();
         wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
         exit;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `wp-cli` installed : https://wp-cli.org/
You can try a `wp cache type` command from the root of your folder.

If you get `Unknown` it's a plugin issue or a mu-plugin issue I think.

If it's `Default`, there is no WP cache plugin (I'm not really sure about that but 90% sure).

After that you may grep for 'WP_CACHE' from the root of your project.

```
grep -Ri 'WP_CACHE' *
```

You'll be able to delete this constant and remove the cache folder. Things going to work. (I hope for you)