# WordPress 5 boot-sequence / load-order

Tags: plugins

I'm looking for an overview (hopefully by way of a graphical representation) of the WordPress boot-sequence / load-order.

The resources I have found, e.g. [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence) tend to be several years old, but I have read that many things changed with WP5.

Is there any up-to-date resource?

Comment: The 'Make sense of WP core load' diagram still looks right to me. What do you think has changed?

Comment: and [the answer with the colourful diagram further down](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/366892/3276) was written this year, although I don't think it's as easy to follow.