# Add class to woocommerce checkout body based on filter

Tags: filters, body-class

I am trying to add a class to a checkout page if the checkout contains a subscription renewal.
Woocommerce provides [`wcs_cart_contains_renewal()`](https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/includes/wcs-renewal-functions.php#L71) to check.
I am using this code but obviously missing something as it's not working.

```
$cart_items = wcs_cart_contains_renewal();
    if ( ! empty( $cart_items ) ) {

    add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
    function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
        $classes[] = 'renewal-order';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Any help on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cjbj noted in a comment, this is probably a timing issue. This means that instead of directly adding the code to `functions.php` you need to wrap it inside a callback function and attach it to a later firing action. WordPress, themes and plugins too, [loads](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence) and [does](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) things in certain order. Thus some code needs to be added with actions to make them properly.

Personally, I usually add `body_class` filtering, if it depends on some data, on [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) (*Fires before determining which template to load*) action to make sure the code will have all the data it needs to determine how to filter the classes.

```
// Hook anonymous callback to template_redirect action
add_action(
    'template_redirect',
    function(){
        // Get data
        $cart_items = wcs_cart_contains_renewal();
        // Check for truthy condition
        if ( $cart_items ) {
            // Hook anonymous callback to body_class filter
            add_filter(
                'body_class',
                function( $classes ) {
                    // Add additional class
                    $classes[] = 'renewal-order';
                    return $classes;
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```

*You can use named callback instead of anonymous ones, if you wish.*

Comment: That works well thanks, I managed to get it working but your solution does seem more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

The `body_class` filter is called inside the [function with the same name](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/), which is supposed to be in your theme like this: `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Now, you don't make clear where your piece of code is called, but if it is not attached to [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) or another hook inside the `<head>` tag of you page, you are adding a filter to a function that has already been called. As a result nothing happens.

Comment: The code is within my functions.php and my body tag is correct in the head like you have noted. The body_class filter works as expected when it is not within the if statement. What I'm not sure about is if the if statement surrounding that functions is causing the issue.

Comment: In that case apparently `wcs_cart_contains_renewal` returns empty at the moment you call the function. This really sounds like a matter of timing to me.

Answer (score 0):

While I am running with Antti's code I did manage to get it working. I think the issue with my initial code was it needed to be wrapped up within the function.

```
function inline_css() {
    $cart_items = wcs_cart_contains_renewal();
    if ( ! empty( $cart_items ) ) {
    add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
        function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
            $classes[] = 'renewal-order';
        return $classes;
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'inline_css', 0 );
```