# What is the proper way to get logged in user id in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, users

I need to get logged in user id inside my plugin.

Is this the proper way?

```
$root = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
if (file_exists($root.'/wp-load.php')) {
require_once($root.'/wp-load.php');
} 
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

[Otto saying](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) that we shouldn't load wp-load.php file since we have no idea where wp-load.php file located and it doubles the server load.

So I'm really confused.

And one more question..

[Check this Rarst's Image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first/26622#26622)

According to that image wp-load.php loaded before all the plugins. So why all plugin authors include that file again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're inside a plugin, WordPress is already loaded.  You don't need to load it yourself.

Inside whatever function needs the user ID, you need to do two things:

1. Globalize the user data variable
2. Populate the user data variable

Here's some pseudocode:

```
function some_function_that_needs_user_info() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    // Now reference $current_user->ID in your code.
}
```

Comment: FYI: `get_currentuserinfo()` is deprecated as at WordPress 4.5.0. Use `wp_get_current_user()` instead. *... more information [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)*.

Answer (score 6):

Use [**`is_user_logged_in()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) and [**`wp_get_current_user()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user) ([dev docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_get_current_user/)).

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Current user is logged in,
    // so let's get current user info
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // User ID
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So [this plugin](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/socialauth-wp/trunk/feature-friends.php) coded in the wrong way right? (line 12 - 17)

Comment: That's really a separate question. Without digging more into that Plugin, I can't really comment on why it's loading `wp-load.php`. I do know, however, that it is not necessary for getting current user info.

Comment: It's actually necessary for that purpose, due to the fact that it's loading the majority of the WordPress core. My assumption is that this is a part of the plugin that is called outside of the scope of WordPress - such as a remote AJAX call to the file or anything related to that, where you have no access to the WordPress functions such as get_currentuserinfo. However, it's not really a good practice to include the core this way.