# What is the callback sent to add_submenu_page() invoked by WordPress?

Tags: actions, callbacks, add-submenu-page, notices

WordPress tries to be event driven with all it's actions and filters you can hook to. But it also has special functions to create admin pages such as add_submenu_page() which accepts a (callback) $function param.

When does this function actually execute? Between or at which action trigger time?

It must be pretty late in the action order because I've tried hooking to admin_notices from it and it doesn't work. See [Actions Run During an Admin Page Request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request) for the typical action triggering order when in /wp-admin .

**More details**

Why do I want to know this? I'm processing a form from the callback of add_submenu_page() because it's the best place I could think of to process the form POST data, and on validation errors I want to display a simple admin notice "the right way" which is [by hooking a fn into admin_notices](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices). I guess I could just print the notice in a conditional within my html code, or try to process the form at an earlier stage.

Note: I don't like the idea of using admin_post_(action) instead of the callback of add_submenu_page(), it's not useful.

Comment: Summarizing, you give add_submenu_page() a callback function to display the admin screen. I'm also using that callback to process the POST and hook to admin_notices, which doesn't work at that point. So my Q really is when does the callback sent to add_submenu_page() is invoked by WordPress. Thanks, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It must be pretty late in the action order because I've tried hooking
>   to admin_notices from it and it doesn't work.

`$function` callback (param of `add_submenu_page`) is used to **output** the content of admin pages, so it runs when WordPress is actually displaying the markup (body) of page.

That should be pretty clear because you use **`echo`** inside that callback.

In the [Actions Run During an Admin Page Request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request) you linked, it is just before `"in_admin_footer"`.

"`admin_notices`" is also fired when WordPress output the content of admin pages, but just earlier (output of admin notices is on top of admin pages body).

If you need to conditionally output an admin notice, put a condition on "`admin_notices`" callback.

Comment: I like this answer (can't vote up yet due to nil reputation). Do you have any reference or know a way to check when exactly does WordPress output html in the action triggering sequence? I guess that's the underlying question here.

Comment: p.s. this guide has a nice diagram called "Make sense of WP core load" but it's still unclear to me from it where exactly does WP output html. http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters--wp-27373

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel that diagram comes from [this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/35541), it's by our moderator **Rarst**,

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel the output of the html starts when WP include [`admin-header.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-header.php)

Answer (score 1):

> For settings pages that are located in any other location, default admin notices are not displayed automatically. So if your plugin or theme page is located in its own menu, or in a submenu of any menu other than `Settings`, WordPress does not automatically display default admin notices. In such case, you need to invoke `settings_errors()` to display the default `error` and `updated` messages. 
>   - [DigWP.com](https://digwp.com/2016/05/wordpress-admin-notices/)

**References:**

1. [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error)