# How to pass variable to functions.php?

Tags: variables, migration

I have a variable, created in **page.php**, and would like to pass this to a function in **functions.php**.

Possible?

Comment: make it global var in page.php ( $GLOBALS $my_var = 'blah blah';   )and you can call it in you functions.php ( $GLOBALS $my_var ) ( page.php and functions.php ) both tamplate you have yo make it global

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If the function exists in functions.php then your page.php will have access when it gets loaded -- assuming they are the same theme.

Answer (score 0):

I may be dramatically wrong, but I believe not: theme's PHP files are executed after `functions.php`. Check the chart in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/8105).