# Authoritative answer on which boots first - Plugins or Themes?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, codex

I can't seem to find anywhere in the WordPress documentation an authoritative answer on the question on whether a WordPress plugin boots first or whether a WordPress theme boots first.

I need to know the answer because an important development decision I am working on depends on it - as it is related to themes that depend on the presence of certain plug-ins.

And by "authoritative answer", I mean -- is the answer as-it-is just an accident of how WordPress is presently designed - subject to being all up-in-the-wind next version of WordPress --- or is it a standard aspect of how WordPress is supposed to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[See this famous answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/7355) by the equally famous [Rarst](https://www.rarst.net/). Here he charts out the load process of WordPress which hasn't and isn't expected to change any time soon. The process pretty much goes:

1. WordPress Core
2. Must-Use Plugins ( mu-plugins directory )
3. Plugins
4. Themes ( Child before Parent )

Comment: The *should be more famous* Rarst