# How to use a shortcode of a plugin in another plugin php file

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I'm trying to implement reservation function in my web with two plugins of wordpress.

Two plugins are reservation plugin and payment plugin, respectively.

Reservation plugin has some steps for reservation, for example, selecting service, choosing the date, time, etcs.

I want to insert a "payment button" provided by payment plugin in payment step of reservation plugin.

I wrote down below code in php file(for payment step) of reservation plugin,

```
<?php

 if ( shortcode_exists( 'payment_button' ) ) {

 echo nl2br("Payment plugin shortcode exists!\n");
 echo do_shortcode( '[payment_button]' );

} 
 else {
  echo nl2br("No payment plugin shortcode exists!\n");
  }

 ?>
```

With the above code, "Payment plugin shortcode exists!" is printed out but I can't get payment button of payment plugin in my web.

Wordpress built-in shortcode like [gallery] has worked, which I did as a test.

What should I check about two plugins or anything else?

Loading order of two plugins?

Enquescripts order of scripts used in two plugins?

I tried to load reservation plugin later than payment plugin, with adding the below code to main php file of reservation plugin , but this did not work. (reference: https://gist.github.com/bappi-d-great/26808240df88dd1fc3fe)

```
<?php
/*
*
* Use the code at the beginning of a plugin that you want to be laoded at 
last 
*
*/
function this_plugin_last() {
    $wp_path_to_this_file = preg_replace('/(.*)plugins\/(.*)$/', 
WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/$2", __FILE__);
    $this_plugin = plugin_basename(trim($wp_path_to_this_file));
    $active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
    $this_plugin_key = array_search($this_plugin, $active_plugins);
        array_splice($active_plugins, $this_plugin_key, 1);
        array_push($active_plugins, $this_plugin);
        update_option('active_plugins', $active_plugins);
}
add_action("activated_plugin", "this_plugin_last");
```

A little advice about my problem would be helpful to me.

Comment: changing order of loading will not help because on the first step WordPress load all plugins with shortcode definitions, etc, and then it makes the content to display: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first#answer-26622

Comment: from which plugin come the shortcode `payment_button` ? maybe it must be executed in a specific context.

Comment: Yes, you're right, mmm. I don't know that specific context.

Comment: But this `payment_button` shortcode contains some parameters such as price in itself. So, this shortcode can be used in any wordpress page. Clicking `payment_button` shows pop-up windows to go further for payment.