# Need to use an external variable inside a function

Tags: functions

Need help with a theme I'm working on.

Basically I have a variable that's set early called $type

```
<?php
if ( preg_match( "/^kssm-/i", $licensekey )&& preg_match("/@/i", $licensekey) == true) : ?>
<span style="color:#ae5842;">
    <?php print( 'Your License is Active' ); $type = 1; ?>
</span>
```

then I have a function where I want to use the `$type` variable

```
function file_pull() {
    if ( $upgrade_type == 1 ) {
        $import_path = '/main/';

        $files_array = array(
            'start'               => array(),
            'home'                => array(
                'description' => __( 'Importing: Main Templates', 'kss' ),
                'files'       => array(
                    'home.xml',
                ),
            ),

        );
    }
    if ( $upgrade_type == 2 ) {
        $import_path = '/main/';

        $files_array = array(
            'start'               => array(),
            'home'                => array(
                'description' => __( 'Importing: Main Templates', 'kss' ),
                'files'       => array(
                    'page1.xml',
                ),
            ),

        );
    }
}
```

I have tried globals but to no avail. Although that's not an elegant solution.

Anything that's worth a try here?

Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "set early"? When and how is it set? And where is the other function being used?

Comment: Set early by that, it's the $type variable in the first code block and I would like to use it in the function in the second code block but it's not part of the function. That's what I meant

Comment: sorry but from your code it seems like a question which has nothing specific to wordpress. How to not use globals was discussed here enough and probably much more on the internet... just try better googling.

Comment: well I guess it's more of a php question rather than a wp one. but yeah still looking at google and checking if there are available solutions online. but if anybody has an idea here it would be awesome too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right that using globals is inelegant at best. There are almost always better solutions that don't depend on global variables. However, if you pause execution within your `file_pull()` function (e.g. using a debugger), or even just print `$GLOBALS` to your php error log within the scope of your function, does your `$type` variable show up there as part of the globals array?

If not, I'm going to guess that your "first code block" is part of some file that isn't actually executed at the same time as the file that contains your function.

Would help to know where your code blocks are coming from. E.g. functions.php, a file in the plugins directory, etc. It may be helpful to review how WordPress loads all of its files ([Between functions.php, widgets and plugins, which is loaded first?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first)), and even how PHP executes (https://www.sitepoint.com/how-php-executes-from-source-code-to-render/).

(I'm assuming `$upgrade_type` in your example above was mistyped here, and wasn't actually mistyped in your code...otherwise the root issue might be that typo.)

Good luck!