# Using "add_image_size" to register custom image sizes inside plugins not working

Tags: plugin-development, images, hooks

I noticed that most examples of `add_image_size()` is done via the `after_setup_theme` hook.
Which means, for it to register, one has to switch theme and reactivate the theme.

Which is not ideal for me as the website I am working on is already in Production. We can't have the monitoring software notifying the higher ups and ringing alarm that the website went ugly every time we push a new custom image size.

So I thought I can register the new custom image sizes using a plugin. So instead of using the `after_setup_theme` we will use the `register_activation_hook` of the plugin, like so:

```
if (!function_exists('xxxx_add_image_sizes')) {
    function xxxx_add_image_sizes() {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/media.php');

        add_image_size( 'jsa-hero-banner', 1400, ( 1400 / 2 ), true );
        // bootstrap xxl
        add_image_size( 'jsa-bs-sm-ratio-4-3', 576, 576 * ( 3 / 4 ), true );
        // bootstrap sm
        add_image_size( 'jsa-bs-md-ratio-4-3', 768, 768 * ( 3 / 4 ), true );
        // bootstrap md
        add_image_size( 'jsa-bs-lg-ratio-4-3', 992, 992 * ( 3 / 4 ), true );
        // bootstrap lg
        add_image_size( 'jsa-small-thumbnail', 300, 300 * ( 3 / 4 ), true );
        // used for image gallery component, ettc.
        add_image_size( 'gfcq-50-50-image', 519, 675 );
    }

}

if (!function_exists('xxxx_activate')) {
    function xxxx_activate() {
        xxxx_add_image_sizes();
    }
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'xxxx_activate' );
```

I can confirm that the hook is getting called and even the `xxxx_add_image_sizes()` is getting called, but even so, the custom image size is NOT getting registered.

Any thoughts? Is it not possible to register custom image size via plugins?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several misunderstandings about how WordPress works here.

> I noticed that most examples of `add_image_size()` is done via the
> `after_setup_theme` hook. Which means, for it to register, one has to
> switch theme and reactivate the theme.

Firstly, that's not what it means. The `after_setup_theme` hook runs on every page load after the theme has been loaded. You can see the sequence of hooks that run on every page load in [this old answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/39152) (it's still accurate, but may be missing some newer hooks).

This means that `add_image_size()` is being run on every page load, and that's important because it needs to run on every page load.

WordPress is basically a big PHP script that runs every time a page is loaded. So on every page load `add_image_size()` is used to register the image size in some global scope so that other code in WordPress can use it if an image is being generated or displayed during that request. That image size information is not persistent, so if `add_image_size()` is not called during a subsequent request WordPress will not have any information about that image size.

> So I thought I can register the new custom image sizes using a plugin.
> So instead of using the `after_setup_theme` we will use the
> `register_activation_hook` of the plugin, like so:

`register_activation_hook` only runs once, when the plugin is activated, so now `add_image_size()` is only running once which means that on subsequent page loads the image size information being added by that call is no longer available.

So there's no problem in updating the theme to include a new size with `add_image_size()`. Once you've made that update any future images that are uploaded will be made available in that size. The problem is that `add_image_size()` does not and cannot resize any existing images. Only future images that are uploaded will be created in the new size.

To handle existing images you will need to use a plugin like [Regenerate Thubmnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) or the [`wp media regenerate`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/) WP CLI command.

Also, just to address the original wording of the problem, there's no problem with adding image sizes in plugins. Since plugins are loaded before themes you can even use the `after_setup_theme` hook from within a plugin. I'm not sure of the earliest or latest hook that `add_image_size()` can be called in, but `init`, `wp_loaded` or `plugins_loaded` should all work (although `plugins_loaded` won't work from within a theme).

Comment: wow I'm only looking for answer but you gave out knowledge. you're the best! thank you so much