# Why does add_action() not run when placed in register_activation_hook()?

Tags: actions, wp-head

I have questions about executing add_action() in a Wordpress plugin. I was attempting to insert  into the  tag via the plugin i wrote.

I had this (which never ran, btw)

```
function tt_add_GA4_header() 
{
  $ga4code = get_option( '_ga4token' );
  // PHP vars are not globals, rather locals
  
  ?>
  <!-- for Google Analytics 4 -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<?php echo $ga4code; ?>"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', "<?php echo $ga4code;?>");
  </script>
  <?php
}

function tt_add_headers() 
{
  $header_libs = get_option( '_custom_headers' );

  ?>
  <?php if ( isset( $header_libs ) ) { echo $header_libs; } ?>
  <?php
}

function tt_activate() 
{
  add_action('wp_head', 'tt_add_GA4_header');
  add_action('wp_head', 'tt_add_headers');
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'tt_activate' );
```

Chrome's page source showed nothing of the GA4_header and other headers in tt_add_headers.

However, this worked - I placed these two add_action() functions

```
add_action('wp_head', 'tt_add_headers');
add_action('wp_head', 'tt_add_GA4_header');
```

outside the function tt_activate() together with register_activation_hook(). Chrome's Page source now displayed the GA4 header and tt_add_headers. For tt_add_headers, I had to surround the code with  tags or the tt_add_headers will downshifted into the  tag instead of the  tag.

Anyone can provide pointers to educate me:

1. why does `add_action` need to go into main plugin file to be activated instead of using the register_hook_activation()?
2. why must  tags be present in the $header_libs in order to be found in  tag, else the $header_libs will be found in the  tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does `add_action` need to go into main plugin file to be activated
> instead of using the register_hook_activation()?

You've misunderstood how WordPress and PHP work. Any code that does not write to the database or a file is not persistent, and `add_action()` does not do either. Any time a WordPress page is requested by the browser the whole WordPress [lifecycle](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/39152) runs. This includes loading and running plugins.

The way plugins work is that when they run, they can use `add_action()` or `add_filter()` to schedule code to run at later points during the page load. So when you use `add_action()` with `wp_head` you're telling WordPress "when you run the `wp_head` action, please run this code". This means that every time your plugin runs, you need to tell it to add your action, otherwise nothing will be added to `wp_head`.

The mistake you've made is that `register_activation_hook()` only runs whenever the plugin is activated. Any code in the activation hook will not run for subsequent requests.

> why must tags be present in the $header_libs in order to be found in
> tag, else the $header_libs will be found in the tag?

This is just HTML. Any thing inside `<head>` must be in a valid tag, like `<link>`, `<script>`, `<title>` or `<meta>`. You can't just put text inside a `<head>` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. This is my first time with Wordpress plugins. Your explanation is crystal.