# How to get WordPress' hooks/actions run sequence?

Tags: hooks

In what order `add_action` hooks execute?

i.e.

```
init
wp_head
wp_footer
after_theme_setup 
etc...
???
???
???
```

---

## EDIT:

I've also posted my solution.

Comment: **BACK-END VS FRONT-END** : https://www.lance.bio/2017/10/11/wordpress-hooks-and-filters-order-of-precedence/

Answer (score 122, accepted):

> "Data! Data! Data!" he cried impatiently. "I can't make bricks without
> clay."
>
> [Sherlock Holmes - The Adventure of the Copper Beeches](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Adventure_of_the_Copper_Beeches)

So let's gather some **real data** from a vanilla WordPress 5.7.2 install and the TwentyTwelve theme activated with only a single Text widget.

For the home page, the following `do_action / do_action_ref_array` calls are made in the following order (logged out):

```
[0] => mu_plugin_loaded
[1] => muplugins_loaded
[2] => registered_taxonomy
[3] => registered_taxonomy
[4] => registered_taxonomy
[5] => registered_taxonomy
[6] => registered_taxonomy
[7] => registered_post_type
[8] => registered_post_type
[9] => registered_post_type
[10] => registered_post_type
[11] => registered_post_type
[12] => registered_post_type
[13] => registered_post_type
[14] => registered_post_type
[15] => registered_post_type
[16] => registered_post_type
[17] => plugins_loaded
[18] => sanitize_comment_cookies
[19] => wp_roles_init
[20] => setup_theme
[21] => unload_textdomain
[22] => load_textdomain
[23] => after_setup_theme
[24] => load_textdomain
[25] => load_textdomain
[26] => auth_cookie_malformed
[27] => set_current_user
[28] => init
[29] => registered_post_type
[30] => registered_post_type
[31] => registered_post_type
[32] => registered_post_type
[33] => registered_post_type
[34] => registered_post_type
[35] => registered_post_type
[36] => registered_post_type
[37] => registered_post_type
[38] => registered_post_type
[39] => registered_taxonomy
[40] => registered_taxonomy
[41] => registered_taxonomy
[42] => registered_taxonomy
[43] => registered_taxonomy
[44] => widgets_init
[45] => register_sidebar
[46] => register_sidebar
[47] => register_sidebar
[48] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[49] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[50] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[51] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[52] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[53] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[54] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[55] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[56] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[57] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[58] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[59] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[60] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[61] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[62] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[63] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[64] => wp_default_scripts
[65] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[66] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[67] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[68] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[69] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[70] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[71] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[72] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[73] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[74] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[75] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[76] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[77] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[78] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[79] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[80] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[81] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[82] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[83] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[84] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[85] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[86] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[87] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[88] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[89] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[90] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[91] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[92] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[93] => wp_register_sidebar_widget
[94] => wp_sitemaps_init
[95] => wp_loaded
[96] => parse_request
[97] => send_headers
[98] => parse_tax_query
[99] => parse_query
[100] => pre_get_posts
[101] => posts_selection
[102] => wp
[103] => template_redirect
[104] => get_header
[105] => wp_head
[106] => wp_enqueue_scripts
[107] => wp_default_styles
[108] => enqueue_block_assets
[109] => wp_print_styles
[110] => wp_print_scripts
[111] => wp_body_open
[112] => parse_tax_query
[113] => parse_query
[114] => pre_get_posts
[115] => parse_tax_query
[116] => posts_selection
[117] => parse_tax_query
[118] => parse_query
[119] => pre_get_posts
[120] => parse_tax_query
[121] => posts_selection
[122] => parse_tax_query
[123] => parse_query
[124] => pre_get_posts
[125] => parse_tax_query
[126] => posts_selection
[127] => parse_tax_query
[128] => parse_query
[129] => pre_get_posts
[130] => parse_tax_query
[131] => posts_selection
[132] => parse_term_query
[133] => pre_get_terms
[134] => loop_start
[135] => the_post
[136] => get_template_part_content
[137] => get_template_part
[138] => parse_comment_query
[139] => pre_get_comments
[140] => parse_comment_query
[141] => pre_get_comments
[142] => comment_form_comments_closed
[143] => loop_end
[144] => get_sidebar
[145] => dynamic_sidebar_before
[146] => dynamic_sidebar
[147] => dynamic_sidebar_after
[148] => get_footer
[149] => twentytwelve_credits
[150] => wp_footer
[151] => wp_print_footer_scripts
[152] => shutdown
```

using the [must-use](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) plugin:

```
add_action( 'all', function ( $tag ) {
    static $hooks = array();
    // Only do_action / do_action_ref_array hooks.
    if ( did_action( $tag ) ) {
        $hooks[] = $tag;
    }
    if ( 'shutdown' === $tag ) {
        print_r( $hooks );
    }
} );
```

that prints the collected action hooks, for the current page, in the last available core action (shutdown).

If you want to check the order of actions and how many times each one is fired, then you can use for example:

```
add_action ( 'shutdown', function(){
    print_r ( $GLOBALS['wp_actions'] );         
} );
```

or without explicit globals:

```
add_action ( 'shutdown', function() use ( &$wp_actions ) {
    print_r ( $wp_actions );      
} );
```

that outputs the array:

```
[mu_plugin_loaded] => 1
[muplugins_loaded] => 1
[registered_taxonomy] => 10
[registered_post_type] => 20
[plugins_loaded] => 1
[sanitize_comment_cookies] => 1
[wp_roles_init] => 1
[setup_theme] => 1
[unload_textdomain] => 1
[load_textdomain] => 3
[after_setup_theme] => 1
[auth_cookie_malformed] => 1
[set_current_user] => 1
[init] => 1
[widgets_init] => 1
[register_sidebar] => 3
[wp_register_sidebar_widget] => 45
[wp_default_scripts] => 1
[wp_sitemaps_init] => 1
[wp_loaded] => 1
[parse_request] => 1
[send_headers] => 1
[parse_tax_query] => 9
[parse_query] => 5
[pre_get_posts] => 5
[posts_selection] => 5
[wp] => 1
[template_redirect] => 1
[get_header] => 1
[wp_head] => 1
[wp_enqueue_scripts] => 1
[wp_default_styles] => 1
[enqueue_block_assets] => 1
[wp_print_styles] => 1
[wp_print_scripts] => 1
[wp_body_open] => 1
[parse_term_query] => 1
[pre_get_terms] => 1
[loop_start] => 1
[the_post] => 1
[get_template_part_content] => 1
[get_template_part] => 1
[parse_comment_query] => 2
[pre_get_comments] => 2
[comment_form_comments_closed] => 1
[loop_end] => 1
[get_sidebar] => 1
[dynamic_sidebar_before] => 1
[dynamic_sidebar] => 1
[dynamic_sidebar_after] => 1
[get_footer] => 1
[twentytwelve_credits] => 1
[wp_footer] => 1
[wp_print_footer_scripts] => 1
[shutdown] => 1
```

where we can get the total count with `echo array_sum( $GLOBALS['wp_actions'] );`

Here's a prettified version:

```
add_action ( 'shutdown', function() {
    foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_actions'] as $action => $count ) {
        printf( '%s (%d) <br/>' . PHP_EOL, $action, $count );
    }
} );
```

or without explicit globals:

```
add_action ( 'shutdown', function() use ( &$wp_actions ) {
    foreach ( $wp_actions as $action => $count ) {
        printf( '%s (%d) <br/>' . PHP_EOL, $action, $count );
    }
} );
```

to get the following list:

```
mu_plugin_loaded (1)
muplugins_loaded (1)
registered_taxonomy (10)
registered_post_type (20)
plugins_loaded (1)
sanitize_comment_cookies (1)
wp_roles_init (1)
setup_theme (1)
unload_textdomain (1)
load_textdomain (3)
after_setup_theme (1)
auth_cookie_malformed (1)
set_current_user (1)
init (1)
widgets_init (1)
register_sidebar (3)
wp_register_sidebar_widget (45)
wp_default_scripts (1)
wp_sitemaps_init (1)
wp_loaded (1)
update_option (1)
update_option__transient_doing_cron (1)
updated_option (1)
set_transient_doing_cron (1)
setted_transient (1)
requests-requests.before_request (1)
requests-curl.before_request (1)
http_api_curl (1)
requests-curl.before_send (1)
requests-curl.after_send (1)
requests-curl.after_request (1)
requests-requests.before_parse (1)
http_api_debug (1)
parse_request (1)
send_headers (1)
parse_tax_query (9)
parse_query (5)
pre_get_posts (5)
posts_selection (5)
wp (1)
template_redirect (1)
get_header (1)
wp_head (1)
wp_enqueue_scripts (1)
wp_default_styles (1)
enqueue_block_assets (1)
wp_print_styles (1)
wp_print_scripts (1)
wp_body_open (1)
parse_term_query (1)
pre_get_terms (1)
loop_start (1)
the_post (1)
get_template_part_content (1)
get_template_part (1)
parse_comment_query (2)
pre_get_comments (2)
comment_form_comments_closed (1)
loop_end (1)
get_sidebar (1)
dynamic_sidebar_before (1)
dynamic_sidebar (1)
dynamic_sidebar_after (1)
get_footer (1)
twentytwelve_credits (1)
wp_footer (1)
wp_print_footer_scripts (1)
shutdown (1)
```

*PS: You should also check out the great [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin by John Blackbourn. (I'm not related to this plugin)*

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Query Monitor. Seems to be a useful plugin on this case.

Comment: @kraftner thanks for the update, I always planned (but forgot about it) to link directly to the story itself as a proper source, obviously my Sherlock Holmes search foo   wasn't great at that time ;-)

Comment: I liked the quote and wanted to see more context. And as I already had the link for myself why not just update here as well. :)

Comment: This should be a part of codex, I'm serious.

Comment: glad to hear it helps @JackJohansson

Comment: Over 4 yo post and still helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This doesn't actually get the exact sequence because of the grouping by hook name.

Comment: @Walf Please see the updated answer for WP 5.7.2 and the mu-plugin.

Comment: Your updated answer is a significant improvement. However, it may produce no output at all if an error halts execution. Of course, an error tells you where it occurred but knowing the preceding events can be extremely helpful. Also, using print/dump statements is likely to interfere with the request, or be voided entirely if [finishing the request early](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15273676/315024).

Comment: WordPress registers the shutdown action hook as a [shutdown function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) with PHP `register_shutdown_function( 'shutdown_action_hook' )`, so it will run in the end even if e.g. another hook's callback calls `exit()`, triggers an error with `trigger_error()` or throws an uncaught Error. According to PHP docs comment it should also run after timeout. Yes it will not display if fastcgi_finish_request cuts it off, but I think one could log it if printing is a problem.

Comment: Still usefull in 2022: thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear it's still useful @Gas

Answer (score 28):

Here is the WordPress load chart

[image: WordPress Load Chart]

→ [Source by @Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/22534)

Comment: Add at least the [source](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first/26622#26622), or even better: find a duplicate for this question.

Comment: Actually I did not know where I got it from. I had this image saved on my PC. Otherwise I would have done that.

Comment: It's also published on Tom Mc Farlin homepage: The WordPress Page Lifecycle -> https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-page-lifecycle/

Answer (score 3):

## Found Solution!

Thanks *@birgire* for nice answer. I will add to that, `muplugins_loaded` sometimes is not fired, so I will use **`plugins_loaded`** as the most first hook (but at that time, user-authorization is not done yet. If you want to check user's authorization, then `init` is the earliest for that)...

p.s. there exist excellent plugins:

1) [**Query Monitor**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) - You can see everything what happens on the page-load, i.e. duration of each executed function  and much more(view all screenshots on plugin page):

[image]

2) **[WP-DEBUG-BAR](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/)** + **[WP-DEBUG-SLOW-ACTIONS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-slow-actions/)**:

a) debug hooks(**actions**) run list on your site.

b) See duration of each **action** (not function):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The basic sequence can also be found on the official docs:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the @birgire's answer, but it provides a nice report that can be displayed for any URL in a WordPress site. You'll need to be logged-in as an Admin level user, then add `?wp-hooks` onto the end of a URL you want to test.

```
/**
* WordPress Hooks Reference
*
* Dump all action and filter hooks at the bottom of any page
* by adding ?wp-hooks onto the end of the URL while logged-in
* as an Administrator level user.
*/
function kevinlearynet_hooks_reference() {

    // Only shown for Administrator level users when ?list-wp-hooks is added to the URL
    $trigger = isset( $_GET['wp-hooks'] ) && current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
    if ( ! $trigger ) return;

    // Capture and sort filters and hooks
    $filters = array_keys( $GLOBALS['wp_filter'] );
    sort( $filters );
    $actions = array_keys( $GLOBALS['wp_actions'] );

    // Output rough template
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <section class="wp-hooks">
    <h1 class="wp-hooks__h1">WordPress Hooks Reference</h1>
    <div class="wp-hooks__lists">
    <div class="wp-hooks__col">
    <h2 class="wp-hooks__h2">Actions</h2>
    <?php foreach ( $actions as $hook ) : ?>
    <p class="wp-hooks__hook"><?php echo $hook; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="wp-hooks__col">
    <h2 class="wp-hooks__h2">Filters</h2>
    <?php foreach ( $filters as $hook ) : ?>
    <p class="wp-hooks__hook"><?php echo $hook; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <style>
    .wp-hooks {
        padding: 30px;
        margin: 30px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.4;
        height: 50vh;
        min-height: 500px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .wp-hooks__lists {
        display: flex;
    }
    .wp-hooks__col {
        flex: 1;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .wp-hooks__h1 {
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
    .wp-hooks__h2 {
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    .wp-hooks__hook {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    ob_end_flush();
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'kevinlearynet_hooks_reference' );
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I wrote about this on my own, so here's the [original source](https://www.kevinleary.net/list-wordpress-action-filter-hooks/) for reference. This includes a little more detail on decisions behind sorting and functionality.

Answer (score 1):

No two requests are exactly the same. A quick and dirty (but very accurate) way to find out what's going on is to *temporarily* add a line to the start of the `do_action` function in `wp-includes/plugin.php` which logs the `$tag`, e.g.:

```php
if (isset($some_get_or_post_trigger_var)) file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'action.log', "$tag\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

You might want to do the same to `apply_filters` function in the same file. I haven't found a better way to get the complete chronological sequence.