# Is there an action like 'after_register_custom_post_type'?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writing a small plugin for Visual Composer. I need to list all custom post types but I don't know when to call the query to fetch all post types. My plugin gets initialized by `after_setup_theme`, but the function which queries the custom post types don't list custom post types, because its executed too early.

The problem: custom post types can be created within theme files (e.g. `function.php`) or plugins (like `Custom Post Type UI`).

Which action should I use to get all custom post types? I know that [Advanced Custom Fields](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf/) does the same (you can create custom fields for every (custom) post type), but I can't find the piece of code that does the trick.

Comment: Do you mean an action that fires after a post type is registered? That's `registered_post_type`

Comment: Hmmm and what happens if a theme and a plugin registers a custom post type? The action will be fired multiple times, right? I think I need an action or a routine that let me execute my code after all post types are registered.

Comment: Ah OK, I think I misunderstood your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @PieterGoosen mentioned, in a deleted comment, the post types should be registered within a `init` hook callback.

The `after_setup_theme` action is fired before `init`, so that hook will not help you.

Try for example hooks fired after `init`, like `wp_loaded`.

Here's for example [a list of the actions order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162869/26350) from my vanilla install.

Comment: When I saw your first answer and the comments after mine, I thought, damn, did I misread something? Hahahha, had me second guesing there. +1

Comment: hehe it looks like I misunderstood the question at first read, but you were on the right track ;-)