# Can wp_script_is used in pluginA check if a script is being enqueued/registered from pluginB?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, debug

Can `wp_script_is` used in `pluginA` check if a script is being enqueued/registered from `pluginB`?

I have two plugins both of which use Angular. One plugin (pluginA) has `angular.min.js` being loaded across all pages. The other (pluginB) has `angular.min.js` being loaded on only one. I would like to check if `pluginA` has already enqueued Angular but I want to do it from `pluginB`.

For instance, I tried

```
$handle = 'myAppScript.min.js' // this is a concatenated/minified version of the entire pluginA angular app.
$list = 'enqueued' // I also tried all the other $list options.
// if 'myAppScript.min.js' is present, don't register Angular again, otherwise register it.
if (wp_script_is($handle, $list)) {
  return; 
} else {
  wp_register_script( $this->plugin_name . '-ajs', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/angular/angular.min.js', array(), $this->version, false );
}
```

However `wp_script_is` returns false no matter what I try (I double checked with a `var_dump`) and therefore adds Angular again.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Update - I have a working solution to my particular problem using `is_plugin_active`, but I'm still curious if there's an answer to the question. Thanks!

```
    $plugin = 'pluginA/pluginA.php';
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    if (!is_plugin_active($plugin)) {
      wp_register_script( $this->plugin_name . '-ajs', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/angular/angular.min.js', array(), $this->version, false );
    }
```

Comment: When are you calling the function `wp_script_is`? If it is called before the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action is fired, then it should return 0. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll have to recreate the situation. Earlier I pushed the code using `is_plugin_active`.

Comment: Ok that is definitely before scripts are enqueued. Take a look here.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I see you were hooking into `plugins_loaded`, this makes sense because it is fired much earlier than `wp_enqueue_scripts`. It is expected that your function would return 0 at this point.

See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162862/how-to-get-wordpress-hook-run-sequence) for the order in which actions are generally fired.

Try to [add an action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) at `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a late priority to make sure it runs after other enqueued scripts. Then you can [deregister](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#notes) the script and register again with new parameters.

> If you try to register or enqueue an already registered handle with
>   different parameters, the new parameters will be ignored. Instead,
>   use wp_deregister_script() and register the script again with the new
>   parameters.

Edit: Sorry, I misread that. `is_plugin_active` is not an action hook and will immediately return true without telling you whether the script is enqueued. It still stands that you must hook the function `wp_script_is` at `wp_enqueue_scripts` or later.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. There is no better way to determine script is enqueued or not. This is efficient way [wp_script_is( $handle, $list )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is)

Just wondering if your $handle name is correct. Make sure **$handle** while checking wp_script_is is the same as when you enqueue script in pluginB. The first parameter is $handle. Refer to this [WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

It says:

## Parameters

**$handle**

(string) (Required) Name of the script. **Should be unique.**

I believe you are using plugin name as a handle in else part.

**Try using same name "AngularJS" or something but must be the same as $handle**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but according to WP codex:

```
wp_script_is( string $handle, string $list = 'enqueued' )
```

`$handle` - unique name of the script

As far as I can see you are using FILE NAME instead which is wrong. By me it has nothing to do with when actions/hooks are being fired coz both of your plugins are fired on `plugins_loaded`.

So, if you check it out this way

```
$handle = 'MY_SCRIPT_NAME'; /* can't really be $this->plugin_name . '-ajs' because it gives 2 different strings */
```

in both of your plugins, only one instance of required JS file will be loaded.