# How do I dequeue js/css at the last possible moment?

Tags: actions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to dequeue the font-awesome stylesheet included with the ninja forms plugin (because I manually include the latest FA via a CDN).

I did this:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
  wp_dequeue_style('nf-font-awesome');
}, 100);
```

However the version included in the plugin still loads.

So, how do I dequeue a script or stylesheet at the very last moment? I'm obviously not dequeing "late enough", and that's why the above isn't working.

What is "later" than `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [used this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162869/177370) to determine which actions were firing, and their order:

```php
add_action( 'shutdown', function(){
    foreach( $GLOBALS['wp_actions'] as $action => $count )
        printf( '%s (%d) <br/>' . PHP_EOL, $action, $count );

});
```

And that showed me that the ninja forms plugin uses a custom action `nf_display_enqueue_scripts`, which is what I used.