# What is the first action or filter executed by wordpress?

Tags: actions, performance, core, request-filter

To mesure performance of a wordpress website i need what is the first filter or action executed by wordpress ?
it seems that **index.php** is the input file of server, there is a way to add a global time variable Programmatically by editing this file when a plugin is installed and add this line:

```
 $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
 define( 'REQUEST_RECEIVED_TIME', $timezone );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the very earliest action hook you can call?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23631/what-is-the-very-earliest-action-hook-you-can-call)

Comment: no it give the hook but for performance there is other stuff before hooks

Comment: You asked what the earliest hook was. That question has the answer. If that’s not what you need then you should ask your actual question.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.mikeinmonospace.com/wordpress-internals-loading-sequence/) is nicely described what and when is loading and why. I recommend also this awesome plugin [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) that helped me also to fix performance issues.

in short:

```
muplugins_loaded
registered_taxonomy
registered_post_type
plugins_loaded
sanitize_comment_cookies
setup_theme
unload_textdomain
load_textdomain
after_setup_theme
auth_cookie_malformed
auth_cookie_valid
set_current_user
init
widgets_init
register_sidebar
wp_register_sidebar_widget
wp_loaded
parse_request
send_headers
parse_tax_query
parse_query
pre_get_posts
posts_selection
wp
template_redirect
wp_default_scripts
wp_default_styles
admin_bar_init
add_admin_bar_menus
get_header
wp_head
wp_enqueue_scripts
wp_print_styles
wp_print_scripts
loop_start
the_post
get_template_part_content
begin_fetch_post_thumbnail_html
end_fetch_post_thumbnail_html
loop_end
get_sidebar
dynamic_sidebar_before
dynamic_sidebar
dynamic_sidebar_after
get_footer
twentytwelve_credits
wp_footer
wp_print_footer_scripts
admin_bar_menu
wp_before_admin_bar_render
wp_after_admin_bar_render
shutdown
```